# Lambda can't reach the internet

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

So I have a lambda function with it's own SG, it resides in a VPC to allow a connection to my RDS. All works there. The problem is with it getting out to the internet. The lambda sg allows inbound from anything in it's SG. On the outbound it allows everything out with dest 0.0.0.0/0. All 3 subnets associated with this VPC have a route to an internet gateway using 0.0.0.0/0.

If I stand up an EC2 instance and associate it with the lambda SG it is able to access the internet just fine. However, my lambda expression is timing out when trying to reach out. What could be going wrong? Thanks!

Comment: did you attach NAT gateway? for lamda I think you need NAT, check this https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/

Answer (score 0):

Need a NAT gateway, IGWs are only for machines with public IPs already. Second question posted to figure out how to mix NAT gateways with machines that have public IPs and an IGW in the same VPC.